# Why secret key is 98 char long in tezos?

Tags: tezos-client, conseiljs

I have tried generating key-pair using Conseiljs and tezbridge. Both are returning the secret key of length 98 and public key of length 54. Why?

It is mentioned in the documentation that tezos use Ed25519 to generate keypair. But in stellar which uses the same algorithm generates keypair of length 56.

Is it using some other algorithm or it is in encrypted form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be 54 for that option. Maybe Stellar has some extra bytes padding?

If the secret key length is 98, then what you have is a full secret key. After you b58decode this, the last 32 chars are the public key.

If secret key length is 54, what you have is actually a seed phrase. b58decode this then use ed25519's NewKeyFromSeed function to get you the private key, and from there, the public key.

[GoLang Tezos Library](https://github.com/goat-systems/go-tezos/blob/51a704c048562c44f68e30d321c4a239cf66b4d6/account.go#L133) Reference

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar Please mark as answered.