# Why does secret_key_hashes have keys of differing lengths?

Tags: cryptography

In my `.tezos-client/secret_keys` file, I have two keys of different lengths. Both start with `edsk` and are unencrypted.

The first is 98 characters long, which I believe is the actual secret key.   The second is 54 characters long, which I believe is a seed. ([Why secret key is 98 char long in tezos?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/why-secret-key-is-98-char-long-in-tezos)).

New keys are always 54 characters long. Is it correct to interpret this as tezos-client is storing seeds in a file called 'secret_keys'? Why would tezos-client not store the full 98 character secret key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ed25519 "secret key" is derived deterministically from a seed. As you point out the seed is shorter than the "secret key" which may make it more practical to work with. Both can be stored in this file.